# How can I choose from list that generated randomly;?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

```
import random

i=1
a = {}
a["Abdullah Gül Üniversitesi(Kayseri)"] = [1, 2, "bob"]
a["Abdullah Gül Üniversitesi2(Kayseri)"] = [3, 4, "bob2"]
a["Abdullah Gül Üniversitesi3(Kayseri)"] = [5, 6, "bob3"]
a["Abdullah Gül Üniversitesi4(Kayseri)"] = [7, 8, "bob4"]
key = random.choice(list(a))
print(key)

# it works until this

w=random.choice(dict(key))
print(w)
```

I want to generate a random list from `a` and it worked correctly but the thing is I can't generate a random value from the first one I created.

Comment: `w = a[key]` ..?

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

i=1
a = {}
a["Abdullah Gül Üniversitesi(Kayseri)"] = [1, 2, "bob"]
a["Abdullah Gül Üniversitesi2(Kayseri)"] = [3, 4, "bob2"]
a["Abdullah Gül Üniversitesi3(Kayseri)"] = [5, 6, "bob3"]
a["Abdullah Gül Üniversitesi4(Kayseri)"] = [7, 8, "bob4"]
key = random.choice(list(a))
print(key)

# it works until this

w=random.choice(a[key])
print(w)
```

Comment: sorry.. missed that

Answer (score 0):

Try generating a random number within the range of your list's length. Then select the random value for the key at the indices of the random number.

```
randomnumber = random.randint(0, a.len()) 

randomchoice = a[randomnumber]
```